# Cant POST with REST API on WordPress

Tags: rest-api, authentication

I'm partially new to wordpress,
I want to POST data from postman to wordpress
as simple as `{"title":"New Rest Post"}`
using `Application Passwords` for auth.

When trying on local wp (http) it works and create new post,
but remotely or any wordpress domain (https) it shows the following msg:

```
{
  "code": "incorrect_password",
  "message": "The provided password is an invalid application password.",
  "data": {
    "status": 401
  }
}
```

Comment: You're sure it's not an invalid application password as per error message?

Comment: This is weird after making many tries with same steps creating creds. with application passwords it worked.